# Why doesn't the 'exists' method evaluate to true even though the document does exist in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm finding a very weird behaviour in my program. At first, businesses can sign up and go to a `businessesPendingAdminApproval` firestore collection. While they are in that collection, the 2nd if statement below `snapshotPending.exists` works (evaluates to `true`).

However, after an admin accepts the business (moves it to the `approvedBusinesses` collection), `snapshotApproved.exists` evaluates to `false`, even though it does exist in that collection. That happens whether I refresh the page or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getOfferedServicesFromDB() {
      const approved = await db.collection('approvedBusinesses').doc(businessId)
      const snapshotApproved = await approved.get()
      //why does the below evaluate to false even though it does exist?
      if (snapshotApproved.exists) { //always evaluates to false
        //...
      } else {
        const pending = await db.collection('businessesPendingAdminApproval').doc(businessId)
        const snapshotPending = await pending.get()
        if (snapshotPending.exists) //evaluates to true while in businessesPendingAdminApproval'
          //...
      }
      return
    }

    getOfferedServicesFromDB()
  }, [])
```

Comment: Please double check your variable `businessId` points to a valid document Id in your collection  `approvedBusinesses`. If it is, then it might be the case that you may not be connected to the database and the firestore SDK is loading documents from the cache instead from the database itself, so you are not getting the most updated results w.r.t the database.
For a quick debugging option, try to disable persistence for firestore and then retry the above query.

Comment: "Why doesn't the 'exists' method evaluate to true even though the document does exist in Firebase?" Your title sounds exactly like the expected behavior. Are you missing a negation somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
const approved = db.collection('approvedBusinesses').doc(businessId)
```

or

```
const snapshotApproved = await db.collection('approvedBusinesses').doc(businessId).get()
```